# Facebook comments: subscription not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, facebook

I have to put facebook comment social plugin in my father's personal website.
Main problem is that website is in html (no asp or php).

Problem: I had to find a way to put the current page url in facebook plugin. i solved reading many solutions with jquery, but it seems to work only after the second page refresh (the first time comment box is loaded... but comments are not published on author timeline..)

this is my code:
in the head section:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.fb-comments').attr("data-href", document.URL);
    });
</script>
```

in body:

```
    <div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>

 window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({
          appId      : 'MY_APP_ID',
          xfbml      : true,
          version    : 'v2.1'
        });
      }; 

<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/it_IT/sdk.js#xfbml=1&appId=MY_APP_ID&version=v2.0";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
  }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>

<script>
    FB.Event.subscribe('comment.create', function(response) {
            alert('comment created: ' + response);        
            $(document).load('mail.php?response='+response);
            });

</script>
```

at the end of the page, the comments box (it has not data-href because is pushed by jquery):

```
   <div class="fb-comments" id="fb-comments" data-numposts="5" data-colorscheme="light"></div>
```

Why it's not working every time?
is code for async loading correct?

example url: http://www.lemiecime.it/cime/fancy.htm  (it's a demo page.. you can put comments)

many thanks

Comment: try to remove the jQuery code `$('.fb-comments').attr("data-href", document.URL);` and leave the `<div class="fb-comments" id="fb-comments" data-numposts="5" data-colorscheme="light"></div>` with no `data-href` attribute. it should automatically get the url of the current page.

Comment: i'm also getting a javascript error in console:
`Uncaught ReferenceError: FB is not defined`

Comment: if I remove jquery the comment box has a yellow warning saying that it's working in compatibility mode without the href reference. And it's not working.
EDIT: without href data-href sometimes it's working and sometimes no.. could you all try to post a commment and see if it's published in your personal timeline? http://www.lemiecime.it/cime/fancy.htm